# Swift - function to return different value based on another variable

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-view

I have a view (view1) to display different data, and I would like that view to change based on another variable.

```
struct View1: View {

let array = myFunc()

var body: some View {
        
    VStack {
    
       Text("\(settings.score)")
            List {
            ForEach(0..<array.count) { section in
        
            NavigationLink(destination: RowDetailView(array: array[section])) {

            RowView(array: array[section])
            }
            }
}
        }
```

In another view I establish an Observable object:

```
class GameSettings: ObservableObject {
@Published var score = 1
}
```

That all works well elsewhere in other views. I can update it as needed.

I have a function to obtain the array variable, and I would like it to return a different array depending upon the current value of "score".

```
func myFunc() -> [arrayModel] {
@StateObject var settings = GameSettings()

if settings.score == 1 {
var array = [ arrayModel(example: example) ]
return array
}
else if settings.score == 2 {
var array = [ arrayModel(example: example) ]
return array
}
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. I have tried various tweaked versions of this, but can't find how to properly implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that `settings.score` isn't *current* in `myFunc`, and if `myFunc` is in a SwiftUI view, you can do the following:

1. Change `@StateObject var settings = GameSettings()` to `@EnvironmentObject var settings: GameSettings`, and move it *outside* `myFunc`.
2. In your `SceneDelegate`, store a reference to `GameSettings()`, like this: `static var gameSettings = GameSettings()`.
3. In your `SceneDelegate`'s `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` function, supply the `ObservedObject` to your views by using the `.environmentObject` modifier, passing in the variable you stored in step #2, like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = ContentView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SceneDelegate.gameSettings))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding to my question. I'm a complete newbie to Swifui, so I have no idea what the SceneDelegte is, so I'm finding it very hard to implement this. As I said, I have no trouble accessing or modifying settings.score, I just want to return a different value of array based on different values of settings.score